# Qt4 window background color

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm running a Qt-based application on RHEL 7.

Using qt4-config, it is possible to change the window background color to any arbitrary value I wish, then 'save' and have the change immediately take effect on any running Qt-based apps.

I want to do this without qt4-config - something I can integrate into a shell script.

I imagine there's a config file somewhere being changed, and perhaps also some action being taken to cause the re-reading of this config file. But I've been unable to find either. Nor have I been able to determine if there's some pre-existing tool which can do this without reinventing the wheel.

I've located `~/.config/Trolltech.conf` but suspect that editing that only represents a portion of what's happening.

Any hints?

Comment: Yeah, you could read qt4-config source code.